# Como cambiar el color con un GestureDetector de un Path SCG en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, app, svg

espero alguien me pueda ayudar, estoy haciendo una aplicación donde el usuario escogerá X imagen que previamente con flutterShapeMaker pase del código SVG a clases como muestro a continuación (solo es 1 de varios paths)

```
class PathUno extends CustomPainter{
  final Color color;
  PathUno(this.color);
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Path path_1 = Path();
    path_1.moveTo(size.width*0.7138889,size.height*0.3569444);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7259804,size.height*0.3599747,size.width*0.7367647,size.height*0.3650253,size.width*0.7468954,size.height*0.3705808);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7586601,size.height*0.3771465,size.width*0.7694444,size.height*0.3844697,size.width*0.7761438,size.height*0.3949495);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7823529,size.height*0.4047980,size.width*0.7794118,size.height*0.4148990,size.width*0.7638889,size.height*0.4190657);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7485294,size.height*0.4231061,size.width*0.7339869,size.height*0.4217172,size.width*0.7187908,size.height*0.4193182);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7040850,size.height*0.4169192,size.width*0.6892157,size.height*0.4148990,size.width*0.6750000,size.height*0.4111111);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6684641,size.height*0.4093434,size.width*0.6620915,size.height*0.4073232,size.width*0.6552288,size.height*0.4061869);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6517974,size.height*0.4055556,size.width*0.6500000,size.height*0.4053030,size.width*0.6517974,size.height*0.4088384);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6647059,size.height*0.4327020,size.width*0.6648693,size.height*0.4574495,size.width*0.6612745,size.height*0.4825758);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6583333,size.height*0.5037879,size.width*0.6514706,size.height*0.5243687,size.width*0.6449346,size.height*0.5450758);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6436275,size.height*0.5491162,size.width*0.6431373,size.height*0.5532828,size.width*0.6421569,size.height*0.5574495);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6415033,size.height*0.5599747,size.width*0.6424837,size.height*0.5606061,size.width*0.6457516,size.height*0.5606061);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6566993,size.height*0.5606061,size.width*0.6648693,size.height*0.5648990,size.width*0.6709150,size.height*0.5715909);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6844771,size.height*0.5866162,size.width*0.6910131,size.height*0.6037879,size.width*0.6968954,size.height*0.6212121);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7052288,size.height*0.6462121,size.width*0.7102941,size.height*0.6715909,size.width*0.7142157,size.height*0.6972222);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7200980,size.height*0.7352273,size.width*0.7227124,size.height*0.7733586,size.width*0.7248366,size.height*0.8114899);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7253268,size.height*0.8212121,size.width*0.7205882,size.height*0.8281566,size.width*0.7104575,size.height*0.8339646);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7021242,size.height*0.8387626,size.width*0.6928105,size.height*0.8406566,size.width*0.6834967,size.height*0.8433081);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6633987,size.height*0.8489899,size.width*0.6424837,size.height*0.8484848,size.width*0.6217320,size.height*0.8484848);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6098039,size.height*0.8484848,size.width*0.5975490,size.height*0.8486111,size.width*0.5859477,size.height*0.8458333);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5792484,size.height*0.8441919,size.width*0.5722222,size.height*0.8425505,size.width*0.5663399,size.height*0.8393939);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5620915,size.height*0.8372475,size.width*0.5602941,size.height*0.8338384,size.width*0.5599673,size.height*0.8303030);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5596405,size.height*0.8271465,size.width*0.5578431,size.height*0.8270202,size.width*0.5545752,size.height*0.8270202);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5460784,size.height*0.8271465,size.width*0.5377451,size.height*0.8271465,size.width*0.5292484,size.height*0.8271465);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5276144,size.height*0.8271465,size.width*0.5259804,size.height*0.8271465,size.width*0.5245098,size.height*0.8268939);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5163399,size.height*0.8252525,size.width*0.5160131,size.height*0.8251263,size.width*0.5147059,size.height*0.8316919);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5114379,size.height*0.8479798,size.width*0.4944444,size.height*0.8568182,size.width*0.4725490,size.height*0.8595960);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4442810,size.height*0.8631313,size.width*0.4156863,size.height*0.8623737,size.width*0.3870915,size.height*0.8607323);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3813725,size.height*0.8603535,size.width*0.3756536,size.height*0.8597222,size.width*0.3699346,size.height*0.8584596);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3537582,size.height*0.8547980,size.width*0.3470588,size.height*0.8459596,size.width*0.3511438,size.height*0.8343434);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3524510,size.height*0.8306818,size.width*0.3506536,size.height*0.8303030,size.width*0.3468954,size.height*0.8309343);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3235294,size.height*0.8347222,size.width*0.3001634,size.height*0.8329545,size.width*0.2766340,size.height*0.8324495);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.2714052,size.height*0.8323232,size.width*0.2661765,size.height*0.8315657,size.width*0.2612745,size.height*0.8301768);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.2519608,size.height*0.8275253,size.width*0.2480392,size.height*0.8204545,size.width*0.2509804,size.height*0.8122475);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.2532680,size.height*0.8060606,size.width*0.2568627,size.height*0.8003788,size.width*0.2609477,size.height*0.7949495);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.2803922,size.height*0.7688131,size.width*0.2924837,size.height*0.7405303,size.width*0.3011438,size.height*0.7112374);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3174837,size.height*0.6559343,size.width*0.3205882,size.height*0.5996212,size.width*0.3202614,size.height*0.5431818);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3202614,size.height*0.5411616,size.width*0.3204248,size.height*0.5391414,size.width*0.3204248,size.height*0.5371212);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3227124,size.height*0.5395202,size.width*0.3251634,size.height*0.5419192,size.width*0.3274510,size.height*0.5443182);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3256536,size.height*0.5453283,size.width*0.3261438,size.height*0.5468434,size.width*0.3261438,size.height*0.5482323);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3263072,size.height*0.5751263,size.width*0.3253268,size.height*0.6018939,size.width*0.3227124,size.height*0.6287879);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3210784,size.height*0.6445707,size.width*0.3187908,size.height*0.6602273,size.width*0.3158497,size.height*0.6758838);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3116013,size.height*0.6981061,size.width*0.3055556,size.height*0.7202020,size.width*0.2968954,size.height*0.7416667);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.2910131,size.height*0.7563131,size.width*0.2839869,size.height*0.7707071,size.width*0.2751634,size.height*0.7844697);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.2694444,size.height*0.7931818,size.width*0.2625817,size.height*0.8013889,size.width*0.2580065,size.height*0.8106061);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.2534314,size.height*0.8200758,size.width*0.2570261,size.height*0.8261364,size.width*0.2699346,size.height*0.8272727);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.2937908,size.height*0.8292929,size.width*0.3178105,size.height*0.8297980,size.width*0.3415033,size.height*0.8271465);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3477124,size.height*0.8265152,size.width*0.3549020,size.height*0.8251263,size.width*0.3576797,size.height*0.8185606);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3660131,size.height*0.7984848,size.width*0.3743464,size.height*0.7784091,size.width*0.3802288,size.height*0.7578283);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3916667,size.height*0.7183081,size.width*0.3973856,size.height*0.6782828,size.width*0.3988562,size.height*0.6378788);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3995098,size.height*0.6189394,size.width*0.3988562,size.height*0.6000000,size.width*0.3990196,size.height*0.5809343);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3990196,size.height*0.5773990,size.width*0.3982026,size.height*0.5751263,size.width*0.3933007,size.height*0.5746212);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3995098,size.height*0.5746212,size.width*0.4055556,size.height*0.5746212,size.width*0.4117647,size.height*0.5746212);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4099673,size.height*0.5762626,size.width*0.4045752,size.height*0.5738636,size.width*0.4050654,size.height*0.5786616);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4068627,size.height*0.5998737,size.width*0.4062092,size.height*0.6212121,size.width*0.4052288,size.height*0.6424242);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4039216,size.height*0.6722222,size.width*0.4003268,size.height*0.7018939,size.width*0.3937908,size.height*0.7313131);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3874183,size.height*0.7598485,size.width*0.3787582,size.height*0.7877525,size.width*0.3658497,size.height*0.8150253);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3627451,size.height*0.8215909,size.width*0.3596405,size.height*0.8281566,size.width*0.3571895,size.height*0.8348485);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3542484,size.height*0.8431818,size.width*0.3563725,size.height*0.8481061,size.width*0.3637255,size.height*0.8510101);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3686275,size.height*0.8529040,size.width*0.3738562,size.height*0.8546717,size.width*0.3792484,size.height*0.8554293);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4034314,size.height*0.8585859,size.width*0.4277778,size.height*0.8574495,size.width*0.4521242,size.height*0.8570707);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4643791,size.height*0.8569444,size.width*0.4761438,size.height*0.8540404,size.width*0.4875817,size.height*0.8507576);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4995098,size.height*0.8473485,size.width*0.5070261,size.height*0.8406566,size.width*0.5086601,size.height*0.8309343);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5127451,size.height*0.8061869,size.width*0.5150327,size.height*0.7811869,size.width*0.5158497,size.height*0.7561869);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5171569,size.height*0.7166667,size.width*0.5148693,size.height*0.6773990,size.width*0.5065359,size.height*0.6382576);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5013072,size.height*0.6137626,size.width*0.4941176,size.height*0.5896465,size.width*0.4828431,size.height*0.5662879);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4792484,size.height*0.5588384,size.width*0.4761438,size.height*0.5513889,size.width*0.4728758,size.height*0.5438131);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4723856,size.height*0.5428030,size.width*0.4718954,size.height*0.5409091,size.width*0.4735294,size.height*0.5404040);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4754902,size.height*0.5397727,size.width*0.4758170,size.height*0.5415404,size.width*0.4764706,size.height*0.5426768);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4789216,size.height*0.5463384,size.width*0.4823529,size.height*0.5497475,size.width*0.4838235,size.height*0.5537879);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4846405,size.height*0.5559343,size.width*0.4864379,size.height*0.5561869,size.width*0.4893791,size.height*0.5560606);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5014706,size.height*0.5553030,size.width*0.5129085,size.height*0.5525253,size.width*0.5240196,size.height*0.5489899);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5303922,size.height*0.5468434,size.width*0.5364379,size.height*0.5444444,size.width*0.5423203,size.height*0.5411616);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5588235,size.height*0.5319444,size.width*0.5683007,size.height*0.5191919,size.width*0.5756536,size.height*0.5050505);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5813725,size.height*0.4940657,size.width*0.5836601,size.height*0.4827020,size.width*0.5844771,size.height*0.4709596);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5867647,size.height*0.4806818,size.width*0.5867647,size.height*0.4904040,size.width*0.5839869,size.height*0.5000000);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5795752,size.height*0.5151515,size.width*0.5705882,size.height*0.5284091,size.width*0.5558824,size.height*0.5392677);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5537582,size.height*0.5407828,size.width*0.5524510,size.height*0.5425505,size.width*0.5542484,size.height*0.5445707);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5571895,size.height*0.5479798,size.width*0.5583333,size.height*0.5518939,size.width*0.5606209,size.height*0.5555556);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5692810,size.height*0.5695707,size.width*0.5759804,size.height*0.5842172,size.width*0.5818627,size.height*0.5991162);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5913399,size.height*0.6228535,size.width*0.5980392,size.height*0.6470960,size.width*0.6009804,size.height*0.6719697);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6037582,size.height*0.6955808,size.width*0.6032680,size.height*0.7190657,size.width*0.5988562,size.height*0.7425505);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5936275,size.height*0.7708333,size.width*0.5831699,size.height*0.7979798,size.width*0.5676471,size.height*0.8238636);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5651961,size.height*0.8280303,size.width*0.5650327,size.height*0.8314394,size.width*0.5702614,size.height*0.8349747);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5751634,size.height*0.8382576,size.width*0.5807190,size.height*0.8393939,size.width*0.5866013,size.height*0.8402778);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6078431,size.height*0.8431818,size.width*0.6292484,size.height*0.8433081,size.width*0.6508170,size.height*0.8422980);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6702614,size.height*0.8414141,size.width*0.6890523,size.height*0.8388889,size.width*0.7057190,size.height*0.8305556);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7138889,size.height*0.8263889,size.width*0.7194444,size.height*0.8212121,size.width*0.7189542,size.height*0.8131313);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7176471,size.height*0.7959596,size.width*0.7169935,size.height*0.7786616,size.width*0.7156863,size.height*0.7614899);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7132353,size.height*0.7305556,size.width*0.7098039,size.height*0.6996212,size.width*0.7032680,size.height*0.6689394);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6968954,size.height*0.6386364,size.width*0.6900327,size.height*0.6083333,size.width*0.6714052,size.height*0.5806818);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6674837,size.height*0.5747475,size.width*0.6629085,size.height*0.5685606,size.width*0.6535948,size.height*0.5662879);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6464052,size.height*0.5646465,size.width*0.6429739,size.height*0.5661616,size.width*0.6413399,size.height*0.5714646);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6410131,size.height*0.5728535,size.width*0.6408497,size.height*0.5747475,size.width*0.6385621,size.height*0.5746212);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6362745,size.height*0.5744949,size.width*0.6366013,size.height*0.5726010,size.width*0.6362745,size.height*0.5712121);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6341503,size.height*0.5625000,size.width*0.6361111,size.height*0.5537879,size.width*0.6387255,size.height*0.5453283);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6449346,size.height*0.5243687,size.width*0.6526144,size.height*0.5035354,size.width*0.6553922,size.height*0.4820707);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6581699,size.height*0.4609848,size.width*0.6586601,size.height*0.4398990,size.width*0.6506536,size.height*0.4193182);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6455882,size.height*0.4060606,size.width*0.6390523,size.height*0.4015152,size.width*0.6233660,size.height*0.4003788);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6266340,size.height*0.4047980,size.width*0.6300654,size.height*0.4085859,size.width*0.6370915,size.height*0.4088384);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6390523,size.height*0.4089646,size.width*0.6416667,size.height*0.4092172,size.width*0.6410131,size.height*0.4107323);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6395425,size.height*0.4140152,size.width*0.6429739,size.height*0.4154040,size.width*0.6442810,size.height*0.4175505);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6452614,size.height*0.4193182,size.width*0.6483660,size.height*0.4212121,size.width*0.6444444,size.height*0.4229798);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6413399,size.height*0.4203283,size.width*0.6410131,size.height*0.4164141,size.width*0.6372549,size.height*0.4141414);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6362745,size.height*0.4135101,size.width*0.6356209,size.height*0.4125000,size.width*0.6343137,size.height*0.4131313);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6328431,size.height*0.4137626,size.width*0.6339869,size.height*0.4147727,size.width*0.6343137,size.height*0.4155303);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6369281,size.height*0.4217172,size.width*0.6361111,size.height*0.4276515,size.width*0.6328431,size.height*0.4335859);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6395425,size.height*0.4330808,size.width*0.6397059,size.height*0.4330808,size.width*0.6383987,size.height*0.4372475);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6370915,size.height*0.4388889,size.width*0.6357843,size.height*0.4405303,size.width*0.6346405,size.height*0.4422980);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6328431,size.height*0.4450758,size.width*0.6305556,size.height*0.4455808,size.width*0.6274510,size.height*0.4436869);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6258170,size.height*0.4420455,size.width*0.6251634,size.height*0.4385101,size.width*0.6210784,size.height*0.4417929);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6168301,size.height*0.4426768,size.width*0.6125817,size.height*0.4435606,size.width*0.6083333,size.height*0.4444444);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6075163,size.height*0.4454545,size.width*0.6060458,size.height*0.4464646,size.width*0.6058824,size.height*0.4474747);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6055556,size.height*0.4508838,size.width*0.6042484,size.height*0.4522727,size.width*0.6000000,size.height*0.4502525);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5967320,size.height*0.4494949,size.width*0.5982026,size.height*0.4453283,size.width*0.5931373,size.height*0.4453283);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5754902,size.height*0.4452020,size.width*0.5584967,size.height*0.4428030,size.width*0.5418301,size.height*0.4375000);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5294118,size.height*0.4335859,size.width*0.5174837,size.height*0.4291667,size.width*0.5058824,size.height*0.4238636);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5029412,size.height*0.4226010,size.width*0.5001634,size.height*0.4210859,size.width*0.4973856,size.height*0.4196970);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4913399,size.height*0.4165404,size.width*0.4859477,size.height*0.4125000,size.width*0.4787582,size.height*0.4106061);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4805556,size.height*0.4078283,size.width*0.4846405,size.height*0.4075758,size.width*0.4875817,size.height*0.4063131);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4995098,size.height*0.4178030,size.width*0.5339869,size.height*0.4214646,size.width*0.5500000,size.height*0.4135101);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5580065,size.height*0.4094697,size.width*0.5637255,size.height*0.4003788,size.width*0.5560458,size.height*0.3925505);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5537582,size.height*0.3902778,size.width*0.5508170,size.height*0.3883838,size.width*0.5488562,size.height*0.3853535);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5503268,size.height*0.3852273,size.width*0.5511438,size.height*0.3849747,size.width*0.5521242,size.height*0.3849747);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5683007,size.height*0.3848485,size.width*0.5843137,size.height*0.3842172,size.width*0.6003268,size.height*0.3813131);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6169935,size.height*0.3782828,size.width*0.6333333,size.height*0.3750000,size.width*0.6477124,size.height*0.3672980);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6532680,size.height*0.3642677,size.width*0.6576797,size.height*0.3604798,size.width*0.6609477,size.height*0.3560606);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6650327,size.height*0.3506313,size.width*0.6635621,size.height*0.3434343,size.width*0.6570261,size.height*0.3402778);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6452614,size.height*0.3344697,size.width*0.6316993,size.height*0.3319444,size.width*0.6181373,size.height*0.3339646);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6083333,size.height*0.3353535,size.width*0.5985294,size.height*0.3363636,size.width*0.5887255,size.height*0.3377525);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5885621,size.height*0.3366162,size.width*0.5895425,size.height*0.3359848,size.width*0.5905229,size.height*0.3353535);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5919935,size.height*0.3345960,size.width*0.5933007,size.height*0.3337121,size.width*0.5949346,size.height*0.3330808);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6163399,size.height*0.3246212,size.width*0.6362745,size.height*0.3143939,size.width*0.6547386,size.height*0.3023990);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6637255,size.height*0.2965909,size.width*0.6718954,size.height*0.2904040,size.width*0.6774510,size.height*0.2823232);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6833333,size.height*0.2736111,size.width*0.6800654,size.height*0.2698232,size.width*0.6718954,size.height*0.2671717);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6619281,size.height*0.2638889,size.width*0.6513072,size.height*0.2654040,size.width*0.6411765,size.height*0.2678030);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6325163,size.height*0.2699495,size.width*0.6238562,size.height*0.2726010,size.width*0.6153595,size.height*0.2750000);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6153595,size.height*0.2724747,size.width*0.6153595,size.height*0.2699495,size.width*0.6153595,size.height*0.2672980);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6271242,size.height*0.2612374,size.width*0.6379085,size.height*0.2539141,size.width*0.6491830,size.height*0.2472222);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6544118,size.height*0.2463384,size.width*0.6584967,size.height*0.2438131,size.width*0.6627451,size.height*0.2414141);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6568627,size.height*0.2425505,size.width*0.6511438,size.height*0.2438131,size.width*0.6460784,size.height*0.2467172);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6361111,size.height*0.2512626,size.width*0.6251634,size.height*0.2545455,size.width*0.6158497,size.height*0.2601010);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6156863,size.height*0.2578283,size.width*0.6156863,size.height*0.2554293,size.width*0.6155229,size.height*0.2531566);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6207516,size.height*0.2527778,size.width*0.6233660,size.height*0.2491162,size.width*0.6276144,size.height*0.2476010);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6356209,size.height*0.2446970,size.width*0.6433007,size.height*0.2415404,size.width*0.6513072,size.height*0.2386364);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6704248,size.height*0.2315657,size.width*0.6898693,size.height*0.2252525,size.width*0.7093137,size.height*0.2186869);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7246732,size.height*0.2135101,size.width*0.7400327,size.height*0.2083333,size.width*0.7532680,size.height*0.2001263);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7563725,size.height*0.1982323,size.width*0.7609477,size.height*0.1964646,size.width*0.7599673,size.height*0.1925505);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7589869,size.height*0.1886364,size.width*0.7539216,size.height*0.1878788,size.width*0.7498366,size.height*0.1867424);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7486928,size.height*0.1864899,size.width*0.7475490,size.height*0.1862374,size.width*0.7464052,size.height*0.1861111);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7354575,size.height*0.1848485,size.width*0.7246732,size.height*0.1842172,size.width*0.7135621,size.height*0.1849747);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6928105,size.height*0.1863636,size.width*0.6723856,size.height*0.1881313,size.width*0.6524510,size.height*0.1934343);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6364379,size.height*0.1976010,size.width*0.6204248,size.height*0.2012626,size.width*0.6057190,size.height*0.2075758);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6037582,size.height*0.2061869,size.width*0.6032680,size.height*0.2042929,size.width*0.6032680,size.height*0.2022727);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6122549,size.height*0.1993687,size.width*0.6215686,size.height*0.1968434,size.width*0.6303922,size.height*0.1936869);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6433007,size.height*0.1888889,size.width*0.6575163,size.height*0.1877525,size.width*0.6709150,size.height*0.1845960);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6901961,size.height*0.1800505,size.width*0.7098039,size.height*0.1791667,size.width*0.7295752,size.height*0.1789141);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7364379,size.height*0.1787879,size.width*0.7431373,size.height*0.1800505,size.width*0.7498366,size.height*0.1809343);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7557190,size.height*0.1816919,size.width*0.7602941,size.height*0.1847222,size.width*0.7640523,size.height*0.1880051);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7673203,size.height*0.1907828,size.width*0.7674837,size.height*0.1943182,size.width*0.7648693,size.height*0.1976010);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7622549,size.height*0.2007576,size.width*0.7593137,size.height*0.2040404,size.width*0.7549020,size.height*0.2060606);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7459150,size.height*0.2101010,size.width*0.7374183,size.height*0.2151515,size.width*0.7276144,size.height*0.2180556);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7263072,size.height*0.2184343,size.width*0.7245098,size.height*0.2186869,size.width*0.7251634,size.height*0.2202020);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7258170,size.height*0.2215909,size.width*0.7276144,size.height*0.2208333,size.width*0.7287582,size.height*0.2205808);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7455882,size.height*0.2176768,size.width*0.7627451,size.height*0.2156566,size.width*0.7799020,size.height*0.2156566);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7947712,size.height*0.2155303,size.width*0.8096405,size.height*0.2161616,size.width*0.8236928,size.height*0.2203283);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8387255,size.height*0.2248737,size.width*0.8434641,size.height*0.2315657,size.width*0.8406863,size.height*0.2440657);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8406863,size.height*0.2443182,size.width*0.8408497,size.height*0.2446970,size.width*0.8408497,size.height*0.2449495);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8385621,size.height*0.2455808,size.width*0.8377451,size.height*0.2470960,size.width*0.8374183,size.height*0.2487374);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8297386,size.height*0.2550505,size.width*0.8214052,size.height*0.2604798,size.width*0.8112745,size.height*0.2643939);

path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6684641,size.height*0.3582071,size.width*0.6643791,size.height*0.3630051,size.width*0.6593137,size.height*0.3670455);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6478758,size.height*0.3758838,size.width*0.6331699,size.height*0.3806818,size.width*0.6181373,size.height*0.3842172);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6022876,size.height*0.3880051,size.width*0.5859477,size.height*0.3895202,size.width*0.5694444,size.height*0.3898990);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5648693,size.height*0.3900253,size.width*0.5622549,size.height*0.3904040,size.width*0.5650327,size.height*0.3946970);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5913399,size.height*0.7523990,size.width*0.5960784,size.height*0.7265152,size.width*0.5959150,size.height*0.6977273);
    path_1.close();
    path_1.moveTo(size.width*0.5230392,size.height*0.7681818);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5240196,size.height*0.7665404,size.width*0.5251634,size.height*0.7654040,size.width*0.5256536,size.height*0.7641414);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5334967,size.height*0.7411616,size.width*0.5388889,size.height*0.7178030,size.width*0.5401961,size.height*0.6940657);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5416667,size.height*0.6688131,size.width*0.5383987,size.height*0.6439394,size.width*0.5312092,size.height*0.6191919);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5254902,size.height*0.5994949,size.width*0.5179739,size.height*0.5803030,size.width*0.5071895,size.height*0.5619949);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5063725,size.height*0.5606061,size.width*0.5060458,size.height*0.5594697,size.width*0.5035948,size.height*0.5597222);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4995098,size.height*0.5601010,size.width*0.4954248,size.height*0.5603535,size.width*0.4915033,size.height*0.5617424);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4885621,size.height*0.5627525,size.width*0.4882353,size.height*0.5637626,size.width*0.4893791,size.height*0.5659091);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4936275,size.height*0.5746212,size.width*0.4968954,size.height*0.5835859,size.width*0.5001634,size.height*0.5924242);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5124183,size.height*0.6253788,size.width*0.5179739,size.height*0.6592172,size.width*0.5209150,size.height*0.6933081);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5230392,size.height*0.7170455,size.width*0.5236928,size.height*0.7407828,size.width*0.5215686,size.height*0.7645202);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5214052,size.height*0.7656566,size.width*0.5214052,size.height*0.7669192,size.width*0.5230392,size.height*0.7681818);
    path_1.close();
    path_1.moveTo(size.width*0.6352941,size.height*0.2631313);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width*0.6351307,size.height*0.2632576);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width*0.6354575,size.height*0.2632576);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width*0.6352941,size.height*0.2631313);
    path_1.close();

    Paint paint_1_fill = Paint()..style=PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint_1_fill.color = color;
    canvas.drawPath(path_1,paint_1_fill);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

al pintar desde el main como muestro a continuación todo bien, me dibuja sustituyendo el color, le puse un onTap a este PathUno, pero no detecta esta area, si presiono cualquier parte de la pantalla me sigue detectando ese onTap,

```
return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        CustomPaint(
            painter: PathUno(Color(0xff000000)),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: 400)),
        CustomPaint(
            painter: PathDos(Color(0xffffffff)),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: 400)),
      ],
    );
```

La idea es que al seleccionar el area PathUno o PathDos o etc... obtenga esa area para poder cambiarle el color, espero me puedan ayudar para saber como se debe poner el gestureDetector correctamente y también como puedo cambiar de color al presionarlo (no importa el color, eso ya lo programo yo "espero")

Gracias

Comment: No tengo ni idea de cuál es la pregunta... ¿Podrías redactarla de otra forma? No veo por ningún lado en tu código el ontap ese que mencionas, por tanto, es normal que no te lo detecte. Otra cosa, ¿por qué te creas un custom paint para usar un svg? ¿No es mejor usar simplemente el svg? Otra cosa, ¿cómo es que el onTap sí te detecta cualquier parte de la pantalla pero no la parte del SVG? Podrías aclarar ese punto. No sé si lo entendí bien.

Comment: el código es ahorita sin el ontap, lo que quiero saber es como implementar de una buena forma el ontap para colorear, y el custom painter lo estoy usando para separar los path del SVG en clases y asi poder manipular

Comment: Envuelve cada custompainternen un gesturedetector y sobre escribe la opción de onTap. Y dentro implementa la lógica para cambiar el color de los custompainter